# SO_KEEPALIVE issue in Mulesoft

Tags: httprequest, mulesoft

we had a Mulesoft app that basically picks message from queue (ActiveMQ), then posts to target app via HTTP request to target's API.

**Runtime:** 4.3.0
**HTTP Connector version:** v1.3.2
**Server:** Windows, On-premise standalone

However, sometimes the message doesn't get sent successfully after picking from queue , and below message can be found in the log -

*WARN  2021-07-10 01:24:46,080 [[masked-app].http.requester.requestConfig.02 SelectorRunner] [event: ] org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport: GRIZZLY0005: Can not set SO_KEEPALIVE to **false**
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.Net.setIntOption0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]*

The flow completed silently without any error after above message, hence no error handling happens.
I found [this](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/WARNING-GRIZZLY0005-Can-not-set-SO-KEEPALIVE-to-true-displayed-on-the-logs) mentioning it is a known bug on Windows server and won’t affect the well behavior of the application, but the document is failing to set SO_KEEPALIVE to true rather than false.

Looks the message didn't get posted successfully as the target system team can't find corresponding incoming request in their log.

It is not acceptable as the message is critical and no one knows unless the target system realizes something is wrong... Not sure if the SO_KEEPALIVE is failing to be set to false is the root cause, could you please share some thoughts? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The is probably unrelated to the warning you mentioned but there doesn't seem to be enough information to identify the actual root cause.

Having said that the version of the HTTP connector is old and it's missing almost 3 years of fixes. Updating the version to the last one should improve the reliability of the application.